# Recursive solutions inside Iterative solutions

Tags: bash, recursion, iteration

I was writing up a bash script to make cd'ing to a Dropbox folder (where I store course work for uni) easier. I decided to take parameters to put me straight in folders for certain weeks, or the parent directory or the directory with all my reference material. I also decided to validate the input using recursion (initially I created an infinite loop by placing the recursive statement in a do while loop). The code is as follows:

```
#!/bin.bash
#changes to ~/Dropbox/UCP120/

function recurCall () {
   echo "Invalid input: $arg1 does not exist."
   echo "Enter a valid input"
   read inputLoop 
   validateInput $inputLoop
}

function validateInput() {
   arg1="$1"
   reference="r"

##snip##

   ##if DIR is !null but non-existent loop and ask for input   
   elif [[ ! -d .../UCP120/"$arg1"/ || ! -d .../UCP120/Week\"$arg1"/ ]]; then     
      recurCall $arg1
      ##Recursive solutions don't require iterative control structures.
      #while [[ snip (see if above) ]]; do
        #   recurCall $arg1
        #done
   fi
}

##Call the function. Get this ball rolling
validateInput $1
```

My questions are:

1. Am I merely lucky this worked? Or did I manage to design this reasonably well?
2. Is recursion a real world viable solution to this? Or useless outside of a learning exercise?
3. Is there ever a real world application for recursion inside iteration like my poorly thought out original attempt?
4. How can I improve this?

Thank you, I apologise if I have asked an inappropriate question. However I am hoping that the internet with its vast experience can help me and my understanding of these concepts.

edit: removed if then statement in validateInput. Swapped function names as they make more sense this way. Removed while conditions to hopefully relieve screen width.

edit: Shortened directory path to relieve screen width even more.

Answer (score 0):

1. This got to work as long as you don't exhaust the shell's stack space by entering thousands and thousands of invalid inputs.
2. Since it works, it is viable. However, I find it harder to grasp than a while-loop, and prefer the latter; but that might be a matter of taste.
3. Certainly there are applications for recursion inside an iteration, but not like here, where the iteration never continues after return from recursion.
4. Refrain from recursion. ;-)